# Getting an error in SSRS report by using LookUp function

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to display data in expression from two different datasets from different servers and different databases. I have used Lookup or LookupSet function without being able to display, because I am getting `#Error`.

```
=LookupSet(Fields!NumeroCours.Value, Fields!Numero.Value, Fields!TitreCourtOfficiel, "Dataset2").
```

The fields `Fields!NumeroCours.Value=Fields!Numero.Value` have the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a case of verifying your fields are referenced properly.  You're missing the `.Value` from the field `TitreCourtOfficiel`.

```
=LookupSet(Fields!NumeroCours.Value, Fields!Numero.Value, Fields!TitreCourtOfficiel.Value, "Dataset2")
```

Comment: Hello, I made correction still getting #Error when i do render my report.

Comment: Are you trying to put the LookupSet into a single textbox?  You may need just Lookup.

Comment: Yes It is in the same textbox. I am going to change with LookUp . By the way, I am also concerned with the fact that one column has number as datatype and other column has only string values. How to convert number to string in SSRS, please. thanks.